# HTML - Javascript - Combine Geocoding and Nearby Search

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I am trying to combine Google Geocoding and Nearby Search in one Searchbox.

The user will type his address and the map should show all Bars near him.

`initmap` Function:

```
function initMap() {
    var setMap = new google.maps.LatLng(50, 9398252, 6.93936825);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: setMap
    });

    var request = {
        location: setMap,
        radius: '5000',
        types: ['bar']
    };

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
        geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
    });

}
```

This is my geocode function:

```
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

This is how I would create Marker:

```
function callback(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
        }
    }
}

function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(place.name);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
```

And here is what my search box looks like:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="floating-panel">
            <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Cologne, Germany" class="form-control">
            <input id="submit" type="button" value="Search" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Until now I can search for a address, so my geocoder should work.
I just don't know how to involve the nearby search process in my code..
Hopefully somebody can help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Once you receive the result of the Geocoding API, you can call the PlacesService API. Knowing that every call to the API will be async, you'll have to wait for the Geocoding callback to launch the PlaceService API.

It will look like:

```
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    var service;
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(resultsMap);
            service.nearbySearch({ location: results[0].geometry.location, radius: 500, type: [ 'bar' ] }, PlaceServiceCallBack); // where PlaceServiceCallBack handles the markers creation
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok, i involved your code to my javascript, but it still does not create markers for the bars.

Comment: It's more about the concepts behind than the actual code. If you just copy/paste my code, it will not work properly. For instance, the "PlaceServiceCallBack" callback doesn't exist in your code so, of course, it will not work (you should either replace this ref with your "callback" function or write a new PlaceServiceCallBack. Do you have any particular problem or question about the concepts involved ?